# Group by column value and get the difference by summing up two fields

Tags: sql, aggregation, cross-apply

I have a table in the format given in the below image as Database Table.
[image]
From that table i want to generate a report. The expected format is given. Help me out with the query.

Comment: Guess you should show what you have tried or the downvotes will be coming, but the description of what you want is quite good.

Comment: Which database it is MYSQL/SQL Server/Oracle?

Comment: Can there be only 2 types and data in given format only?

Comment: Hint: in oracle you could do a select from dual with 4 sub selects, once for each type and then union ... easy but maybe not the best way.

Comment: @maraca: my query is bit lengthy and need to replace the filed names as they are sensitive. But will change col names and post the query soon.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there can be only 2 Types in the table in `T-SQL`you can write a query as:

```
select PaymentType,
[Exists only in old],
diff,
[Exists only in New],
([Exists only in old]+diff+[Exists only in New]) as Total
from
(
-- Fetch Data for Type 1
select 'Type1' as PaymentType,
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Not Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then Old_Type_1
            else 0 end) as 'Exists only in old',
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Not Exists' 
            then New_Type_1
            else 0 end) as 'Exists only in New',
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then Old_Type_1
            else 0 end) - 
         sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then New_Type_1
            else 0 end)   as diff                  
from 
Test
union
-- Fetch Data for Type 2
select 'Type2' as PaymentType,
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Not Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then Old_Type_2
            else 0 end) ,
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Not Exists' 
            then New_Type_2
            else 0 end) ,
       sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then Old_Type_2
            else 0 end) - 
         sum( case when EXIST_IN_New = 'Exists' and EXIST_IN_Old='Exists' 
            then New_Type_2
            else 0 end)                   
from 
Test
)as T
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/VVUFAD97169)</kbd>

Comment: enlightened by ur query. Yes type is fixed no. I am changing my query in ur format. will update soon.